# boost scoped_lock object in if statement evaluation

Tags: c++, boost

The following code compiles

```
scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(some_mutex);
if (!lock) { // What does this means, which function is called
}
```

Since lock is an object what happens inthe **if (!lock)**. Does any overloaded function gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator unspecified_bool_type() const;`, which returns `owns()`, will be called

http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/interprocess/scoped_lock.html

Comment: typedef is done in this file http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/range/detail/safe_bool.hpp